# Plotly layer request specifications

Tags: python, networking, request, plotly

I'm trying to plot a map usiong plotly express like this.

```
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
        df, 
        lat="latitude", 
        lon="longitude", 
        hover_name="abrv", 
        hover_data=["name"],
        color_discrete_sequence=["blue"], 
        zoom=8,
        center = {
            "lat":df["latitude"].values[0], 
            "lon":df["longitude"].values[0],
        },
        size = "size"
    )

fig.update_layout(
    mapbox_style="white-bg",
    mapbox_layers=[
        {
            "below": 'traces',
            "sourcetype": "raster",
            "sourceattribution": "United States Geological Survey",
            "source": [
             "https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
            ]
        }
      ])

fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
```

It goes perfectly on my local machine, but when I put it in an external server it just plots a white map. I've added the url `https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer` to be accepted on the server's firewall, but it stills the same.

Does anyone know the exact request parameters of what I'm doing? (IP, PORT, PROTOCOL, ...)